# css styling for child component in vue js

Tags: vue.js

I'm using reusable code for my contact form, and there are two required fields. In the parent component, i use label as the name of the label tag. For an example, the label full name must have 'Full Name *' and the '*' should be in blue color. I don't have any idea on how to do that. Appreciate if someone could help me.

InputField.vue

```
<template>
  <label for="name">
        {{ label }}
        <span style="color:#0077FF">&nbsp;*</span>
      </label>
</template>
```

Contact.vue

```
<form id="contact-form" @submit.prevent="submitForm">
  <InputField
    v-model="fullName"
    label="Full Name *"
    placeholder="Your full name"
    required
    @handleChange="handleChangeName($event)"
  />
</form>
```

Comment: Please provide any live snippent/demo ?

Comment: @NikleshRaut it just a simple label that you see on any contact form from any websites. This is the design, but i dont know how to change the star symbol to be blue(that means it is required) https://imgur.com/a/8Fp0aMX

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably easiest to do this in CSS.

Add a `required` prop to your component (if you didn't have one already) and use it to add a CSS class to the label

```js
props: {
  label: String,
  required: Boolean,
  placeholder: {
    type: String,
    required: false
  }
}
```

```html
<label :class="{ required }">{{ label }}</label>
```

```html
<style scoped>
label.required:after {
  content: ' *';
  color: #0077FF;
}
</style>
```

Then you can just supply the label without decoration and the CSS will add it automatically for `required` fields.

```html
<InputField required label="Full Name" .../>
```